# Decoding Google Ad click URL

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api, adsense, google-ad-manager

I was looking into ways in which i can decode the Google adclicks URL to the actual website redirect via code...

I have a big db of URLs like following:

```
https://www.google.co.in/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwjY9KL2m4fRAhXTCioKHXEWBN0YABAK&sig=AOD64_3p0RvGkZj0fn81FSXIKtQ9XPVBvg&ctype=5&q=&ved=0ahUKEwialZ72m4fRAhVKwI8KHbGmDB8QvhcIKg&adurl=


https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwjY9KL2m4fRAhXTCioKHXEWBN0YABAM&ohost=www.google.co.in&cid=CAASIuRoPu3Xxj7yyeUtRHLYBy-5952U-NXdaW3ftj91LB2rPAQ&sig=AOD64_0ksuGT2UtbiAEScV_lASVCVh7eFg&ctype=5&q=&ved=0ahUKEwialZ72m4fRAhVKwI8KHbGmDB8QvhcILw&adurl=

http://www.google.com/aclk?gclid=...
```

I am searching for methods to determine what the target website is. Any help appreciated.

Comment: did you have any success with that? without actually following that link?

Comment: Google has an internal big database of randomly generated IDs and corresponding real URLs. Googleadservices URL does not contain any encoded information itself, it contains this ID which is nothing saying to you.

Answer (score -2):

only way to do it is with php file_get_contents